# Consulta en hacer un sistema en C# con SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

estoy intentando hacer un sistema que pueda exportar estos datos y editarlos en el sistema, lo único que se me complica donde pueden observar la línea 136 donde el NºOrden es 073/074 es porque los datos del Cargo Estructural "DIRECTOR DE SISTEMA ADMINISTRATIVO I" se repiten por eso en el total salen "2", o sea son 2 filas iguales pero lo resumen uniendo esos 2 códigos, eso es lo que se me complica desarrollarlo en C# con Sql Server.

Cuando ya este todo, quisiera exportarlo a excel tal y como se ve en la imagen...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que lo mejor es que las separes en 2 filas aunque sean los mismos datos, ya que según a como lo veo el numero de orden, vendría siendo tu id, y tus números id no se pueden guardar así como en la hoja de excel

Comment: Hola Hector Ramos: Si pegas la definicion de tus tablas, y un pequeño ejemplo con los datos, se puede realizar algo que te permita obtener eso sin problemas.

Comment: Claro los datos estarán separados en la datagridview pero al momento que exporte al excel, si detecta que hay filas iguales, tiene que unir esos códigos pero crearía otro campo en mi tabla aparte del código verdadero.

Answer (score 0):

Da lo mismo que 2 o más filas esten repetidas porque al final lo que usted va a hacer es algo como : "update nombreTabla set nombreCampo='Algo aquí'  **where** algo" y el where va a actualizar todas  las filas que cumplan con la condición por lo que no veo problema alguno.